# Vortaro pri klinikaj vortoj... Estas unu?

Tags: single-word-requests

Komputeko estas grava fonto pri 'teĥnikaj vortoj'. Mia demando estas la sama sed pri 'klinikaj vortoj'.

Ekzemple: (en la angla) meta-analysis,  spondylolisthesis, lumbago, aetiology, interbody fusion, heterogeneity, biomechanics etc.

Searching, I can find sometime one source with a translation... but is it enough to be comfortable using such a one-shot in an official settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi povas trovi terminarojn por pluraj fakoj. Ekzemple, por medicino, [tiun ĉi](https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Esperanta_Medicina_Terminaro_(Hradil_1979)).

Esperanto, same kiel pluraj aliaj lingvoj, ne havas la sufiĉan interagon teĥnikan en ĉiu fako. Tio malfaciligas la establon de terminaroj. Eĉ lingvoj kun dekoj da milonoj da parolantoj strebas akompani la anglajn aŭ grek/latinajn terminojn.

Dependas iom de tiu, kiu legos aŭ aŭskultos vin. Tre verŝajne, se vi volas mencii [spondylolisthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spondylolisthesis) vi povas diri ion kiel *vertebra misŝovo*. Se vi komprenas la vorton kaj regas la lingvon, vi povos klarigi tion alimaniere (vi menciis unufojan uzon).

*Misŝovo* estas nur ekzemplo, simpla *ŝovo* povas esti sufiĉe priskriba, aŭ *misloko* se vi iel volas priparoli la agenton kaj ne la efikon. Estu kreema, ni havas amason da rimedoj lingvaj.

Comment: Mirinde. Dankon pro vi (Esperanta_Medicina_Terminaro), mi eblis trovi "Lexique et dictionnaire médical français-espéranto"
http://vortareto.free.fr/.
Precize kion mi bezonas. Ankaraŭ... dankon!

Answer (score 0):

Dankon pro la helpon de Eduardo Trápani, kiu proponis...

https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Esperanta_Medicina_Terminaro_(Hradil_1979)

... mi trovis:

http://umea.fontoj.net/terminologio/

kaj

"Pri medicina terminologio en Esperantujo…" de Christoph Klawe:
https://interrev.com/mir/index.php/mir/article/view/3/1

kaj

"Lexique et dictionnaire médical français-espéranto"
http://vortareto.free.fr/